# Change of WPF Datagrid Cell's DataTemplate caused not desired result

Tags: wpf, datagrid, cell, datatemplate

I have a WPF DataGrid, And I have modified it's first column's cell templete as shown below:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Margin="0">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding W_NAME, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                     BorderThickness="0" 
                                     Background="Transparent"/>
                            <Button Grid.Column="1" Width="20"  
                                    Background="Transparent"
                                    IsEnabled="{Binding CantFound}"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <Image Source="/Resources/Pictures/Search.png"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Button>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

I have also the second "ordinary" {not modified} column, called ID (type of int).

Not desired result appears as shown below:

**step 1:** I open the user control where my datagrid is:

[image]

**step 2:** I click the first cell to write something in it (For some reason, it is enough only one click to put cursor in it. An "ordinary" cell needs 2 - one for focus and one - to put cursor in it)

[image]

**step 3:** I write something in it (this cell is still focused)

[image]

**step 4:** I click for the first time the second cell (And it gets focus only).

[image]

**step 5:** I click one more time the second cell (cursor is there and default value is written automatically). at this point value in first cell is dissapeared.

[image]

**step 6:** I write my value in the second cell:

[image]

**step 7:** I press the enter button on my keyboard and this happens

[image]

Maybe the reason of it is relatively simple, but I fount it difficult to describe it well only with words.

Comment: The TextBox should be in the CellEditingTemplate. The CellTemplate should contain a read-only TextBlock. That's how the built-in DataGridTextColumn works.

Comment: I tried it, but now is another problem. The value in the first cell appears only when I click this cell twice

Comment: You need both a CellTemplate with a TextBlock and a CellEditingTemplate with a TextBox. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CellTemplate` of the column is supposed to include a read-only `TextBlock`. You should put the editable `TextBox` in the `CellEditingTemplate`.

That's how the built-in `DataGridTextColumn` works. You see a `TextBlock` by default and when you double-click on the cell to enter the edit mode, a `TextBox` appears. The `Text` property of the `TextBlock` and the `Text` property of the `TextBox` are bound to the same source property.

Comment: It means that I have to have textblock and textbox too? One in cellTemplate and second in cellEditingTemplate

Comment: Yes, you should define a CellTemplate with a TextBlock *and* a CellEditingTemplate with a TextBox.